# In zsh shell, how do I ensure my export variable command in my source file is re-run fresh each time?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I have a zsh shell on MacOS and have a `~/.bash_profile` source file which contains a line:

```
export API_TOKEN=$(generateAPIToken -type new)
```

where `generateAPIToken` is a binary and `-type` the flag. Normally if I were to run `generateAPIToken -type new` directly in my command line, it outputs the new token.

However, I have another script that sources in `API_TOKEN` as an environment variable and I've noticed sometimes it doesn't seem to re-run the binary again. How can I ensure that accessing `API_TOKEN` forces a fresh run of the binary each time? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, the answer is that you can't. Environment variables (and variables in general) contain *static data*, and will therefore contain the same value over and over again (until something -- not the variable itself -- changes it). Bash has some variable-like things (like `$RANDOM`) that don't behave this way, but they're not actually variables, they're specially implemented in bash itself and there's no way to create your own (and they also can't be made into environment variables).

Comment: Possibly an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why are you storing this information in an env var if you need to generate a new token every time you need one?

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. You say that you are using `zsh`, but what then are you doing with a _bash_ startup file? In general, if you run a command which needs an environment variable for a certain value, you have to set it to this value. If you want the value to persist only for the execution of the script, you can prepend the script invocation with the setting, as in `API_TOKEN=something YOURCOMMAND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have another script that sources in `API_TOKEN` as an environment variable and I've noticed sometimes it doesn't seem to re-run the binary again. How can I ensure that accessing API_TOKEN forces a fresh run of the binary each time?

Given

> ```
> export API_TOKEN=$(generateAPIToken -type new)
> ```

, *accessing* the `API_TOKEN` variable **never** causes the binary to run.  This ... `$(generateAPIToken -type new)` ... is a "command substitution". It runs the command inside when the command containing it -- the variable assignment -- is executed.  The output captured by that one run will be retained as the value of `API_TOKEN` until a different value is assigned.

If you `source` the file containing that command then the command will be executed.  That can get you a different value for `API_TOKEN`, but afterward just checking its value via `$API_TOKEN` does not run the command again.

Possibly you want to define a shell function instead of a variable, though it would not simplify very much over what you already have:

```
api_token() {
  generateAPIToken -type new
}
```

Among the ways you might use that would be a command substitution, `$(api_token)`, as opposed to the parameter expansion you were trying to use before (`$API_TOKEN` or `${API_TOKEN}`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your interactive shell is really zsh (not sure about it, because you are also mentioning .bash_profile).

Say further that your binary is `mybin`, and *mybin* is also in your PATH, and every time you run *mybin*, you want to have a freshly generated token in your environment variable.

You can do it by defining a shell function

```
mybin() {
  API_TOKEN=$(generateAPIToken -type new) =mybin
}
```

Now running *mybin* sets the specific API_TOKEN just for this one execution.

Note that `=mybin` ensures that the *mybin* command from your `path` is executed, and prevents a recursive invocation of your shell function.

Since this shell function is intended for interactive use, I would put it into ~/.zshrc. If you need this also from other scripts, you can put the code into an executable shell script, but of course you then have to be careful about the naming. Maybe it's then easiest to name this shell script differently (for instance `mybin_with_new_token`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing API_TOKEN like this :

```
echo $API_TOKEN
```

try this :

```
echo $(source ~/bash_profile; echo $API_TOKEN)
```